# iOS: How does multitouch affect touchesBegan, Moved and Ended?

Tags: ios, event-handling, multi-touch

I don't have a Apple Developer License yet, so I can't test this out to find out.

When you touch the screen with one finger, I know the NSSet sent into touchesBegan only has one UITouch object in it. When two touches occur at once, the set has two UITouch-es in it.

When you have one finger down, and you touch somewhere else too, I assume touchesBegan would fire again, but would it have both UITouch objects in the NSSet? Or just the one that started?

I assume that whatever the answer is, it holds true for touchesMoved and touchesEnded, but if not, could you let me know about those too?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"number of touches : %d", touches.count);
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"location %f, %f", loc.x, loc.y);
    }
}
```

It turns out yes, the touchesBegan will fire again when one touch is held when making another touch attempt, in which case the second fire reports "number of touches : 1" and the location of the second touch. I don't know for sure whether the same is true for touchesMoved and touchesEnd, but I think so.